pagebreak command not rendering after an R chunk in Quartro
I'm having some issues with the pagebreak command in a .qmd domument in R Markdown. I'm rendering the document as a pdf (it's my thesis). The pagebreak command after an r chunk I use to make a table with kableExtra is not rendering as a pagebreak, but the pagebreak before the code chunk works just fine.
Any insight would be greatly appreciated!
Here's my code chunk and the surrounding sentences:

...to clarify the data were not met with a response. 

{{< pagebreak >}}

{r Border communications table}
#| label: tbl-2
#| tbl-cap: "Data collection from border stakeholders"

border_comms_1 <- read.csv("C:/Users/zsigm/Documents/thesis_draft_files/border_comms_1.csv")

colnames(border_comms_1)[1] <- ""
colnames(border_comms_1)[colnames(border_comms_1) == "Region...if.not.specified."] <- "Region (if not specified)"
colnames(border_comms_1)[colnames(border_comms_1) == "Years.provided"] <- "Years Provided"
colnames(border_comms_1)[colnames(border_comms_1) == "Contact.made...Y.N."] <- "Contact made? (Y/N)"

border_comms_1 %>%
  kable(booktabs = T, format = "latex", escape = F, col.names = linebreak(c("", "Region\n(if not specified)", "Contact made?\n(Y/N)", "Years\nProvided"))) %>% 
    kable_styling(latex_options = "striped") %>%
    kable_styling(latex_options = "scale_down") %>%
    row_spec(0, bold = T) %>%
    pack_rows("California", 1, 2, latex_gap_space = "0.3cm") %>%
    pack_rows("Arizona", 3, 4, hline_before = T, latex_gap_space = "0.3cm") %>%
    pack_rows("Texas", 5, 18, hline_before = T, latex_gap_space = "0.3cm") %>%
    pack_rows("Multiple states", 19, 21, hline_before = T, latex_gap_space = "0.3cm") %>%
    column_spec(1, width = "7cm") %>%
    column_spec(2, width = "5cm") %>%
    column_spec(3, width = "5cm") %>%
    add_footnote(c("data were unusable"), notation = ("symbol"), threeparttable = F)


{{< pagebreak >}}

Missing Migrants Project Data

As there is no centralized reporting mechanism for migrant deaths in the United States...

And here's the YAML:
---
title: "The True Number of Migrant Deaths on the United States-Mexico Border, 2014-2017: A Multiple Systems Estimations Approach"
toc: true
date: "June 2024"
date-format: "MMMM YYYY"
format: pdf
author: 
- name: Zoe Sigman
  affiliations: 
  - name: Hertie School
template-partials: 
 - before-body.tex
 - after-body.tex
editor: visual
execute: 
  echo: false
  warning: false
bibliography: thesis_references.bib
csl: apa-6th-edition.csl
appendix-style: default
interlinespace: double
papersize: a4
indent: true
linestretch: 1.5
fontsize: 12pt
---


Can you try to place your R code inside block with ```{r} ... ``` syntax?

Hey @clemsang  , thanks for responding! It is in an r chunk with the appropriate syntax, but doesn’t look like it pasted properly into SO.

I did manage a work around though, I added text after the table, and the pagebreak after the text. The pagebreak works properly now. There must be some bug about putting a pagebreak after an R chunk in quarto.
